# How to interpret 内緒で買ってこなくちゃ

Tags: translation, contractions

Without further context, what would be the best way to interpret this sentence:

> 内緒で買ってこなくちゃ...

- 内緒 is "secret"
- 買ってこなくちゃ means "must buy"

I know there is another meaning for 買う such as "to value/to provoke." But I'm quite clueless. Is this a kind of idiom/metaphor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have to buy it in secret...!

Perhaps the speaker is talking to someone about a christmas present or birthday present.  Or they need to buy something in secret so that the other party doesn't know they are buying it.

Comment: I wonder why I didn't able to figure it out, now that you've point it out, it really make sense. Thank you so much! :D